# Saving Python objects into memory for repeated use of Python toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I have made a Python toolbox which processes relatively large polyline feature class (millions of features), builds a network graph from it as dictionary of lists, and depending on user selected features in map finds shortest paths between selected features and creates a new selection of these shortest paths. This tool is used repeatedly in one of our workflows. I would love to keep the "network graph" as dictionary of lists in memory. I am aware of in_memory workspace and possibility to convert my dictionary into table and store it like that there.

**I wonder if there is some way to save directly Python objects into generally accessible space (variable) in memory in ArcGIS Pro from Python toolbox?**

Something like in_memory workspace but directly for Python objects (variables).
In my particular case so I can check if this dictionary of lists exists and potentially reuse it if object meets the user settings and other requirements, when the tool is rerun?

Comment: You could do this in ArcMap using Python Add-Ins, which can support persistent objects in memory.  However, Python Add-Ins are not available in ArcGIS Pro.  At least not yet.  Vote it up at:  https://community.esri.com/ideas/10509-python-add-ins-for-arcgis-pro

Comment: @SonofaBeach That is actually exactly what I did in ArcMap, but now we are slowly migrating into ArcGIS Pro and I would like to have some solution for that.

Comment: I wonder whether this may be a Python ([so]) rather than ArcPy (GIS SE) topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687660/keep-persistent-variables-in-memory-between-runs-of-python-script

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you, some answers there seems they could work. I will give it a go and report back.

Comment: maybe using some python cache library like https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property or https://github.com/tkem/cachetools

Comment: @user2856 No, I decided not to as this toolbox is used by multiple people in our office and so far we do not have any dependencies on external python libraries in ArcGIS, and I prefer to keep it like that if possible as not sure how I would manage the dependencies - as it all started with ArcMap without Conda.

Answer (score 3):

In VB .net if you want to save an object to file to be used later, e.g. a dictionary you would serialize it. I believe the equivalent in python is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Be aware not all objects can be "pickled", I would imagine especially anything arcpy related (but I may be wrong).

So if you are extracting network topology as dictionaries then you should be able to pickle them and then reload them back into memory from a well known location at a later date.

My experience with serialization is principally in VB. net so I can't comment on the speed of pickling or the reading back into memory but I would imagine it should be quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts about working with graphs in Python. I believe the base ArcGIS Pro and Desktop both come loaded with Numpy and Scipy, so these should be available to everyone. You could consider using a sparse matrix instead of a dictionary of lists. These will use less memory and be faster computing. You can also perform djikstra's shortest path algorithms using Scipy. You can save the sparse matrix and load it as needed. The matrix is held entirely in memory, which may be a problem for you depending on how large the files are.

Creating graphs (also has links to different shortest path algorithms):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/sparse.csgraph.html

Basic shortest path algorithm:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/sparse.csgraph.html

To save the sparse matrix:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html

Comment: Thank you, I do use scipy for some parts and implementation of Dijkstra using heapq heap which works really well with dictionary of lists.